# How to alter mib-2.system.sysObjectID and related OIDs on default SNMP Agent?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, snmp

When using default Windows SNMP Service (WinXP, Win7) I am able to edit *mib-2.system.sysContact* (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4) and *mib-2.system.sysLocation* (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6) directly on the Agent tab of the SNMP Service Properties dialog.

However, I would like to edit other OIDs in the *mib-2.system subtree*, namely *sysDescr* (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) and *sysObjectID* (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2) and *sysName* (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5), as well. How can I change their values? Is it even possible using default Microsoft SNMP Agent (say, via some registry modification) or is it necessary to install other software (e.g. Windows version of NET-SNMP)?